# How to search for records by using a value in object array from mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to search for records using the below-mentioned Field and code I have used, returning nothing. I'm sure I'm querying wrongly, and can anyone help me build the correct query code?

[image: Field I wanted to serach]

Code I have used:

```
const { id } = req.params;

const requests = await Request.find({
    itemsList: { item: id },
});
```

Return:

```
console.log(requests);

requests: []
```

Comment: Do not post an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const requests = await Request.find({
    "itemsList.item": id,
});
```

will return the entire array if there is a match.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1-tj95pjLa3)

And make sure your data on the query part is matching the type.

In the image, you have a string. Use ObjectId if it is ObjectId.

Comment: ```const requests = await Request.find({ itemsList.item : id });``` showing error and not letting me to execute.

Comment: Sorry for bothering I have found the answer and changed your answer by the working code for me.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
const requests = await Request.find({
    itemsList: { $elemMatch: { item: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) }}},
});
```

Comment: "error": "mongoose is not defined"

Comment: `const mongoose = require('mongoose');`. Make sure this variable is available globally. I copied the code from my working project and it works fine.